# pass string using jquery ajax to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I want to send a hash string to my php file. but failed, can anyone help me please?

my javascript is like this:

```
var hashString = "#support_form";

$.ajax ({
   type: "POST",
   url:"index.php",
   data: hashString,
   success: function() {
      console.log("message sent!");
   }
});
```

and the php:

```
<?php
$theHash = $_POST['hashString'];
?>
```

What should I do? Thanks

Comment: HTML POST expects (name, value) pairs. You are only supplying a value,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the name/value for data

```
data: {hashString:hashString},
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to do like this-

```
$.ajax ({
   type: "POST",
   url:"index.php",
   data: "hashString=value",
   success: function() {
      console.log("message sent!");
   }
});
```

So you can get the value as-

```
$theHash = $_POST['hashString'];
echo $theHase; //will print value
```

Comment: please tell me how to get value in java

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
data: 'hashString=' + encodeURIComponent(hashString),
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code would work if you used an object instead of a string. try this:

```
var hashString = {hashString: "#support_form"};

$.ajax ({
   type: "POST",
   url:"index.php",
   data: hashString,
   success: function() {
      console.log("message sent!");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JS should be this:

```
var hashString = "#support_form";

$.ajax ({
   type: "POST",
   url:"index.php",
   data: {hashString: hashString},
   success: function() {
      console.log("message sent!");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

data key must be of object type
This will work for you

```
var hashString = "#support_form";

$.ajax ({
   type: "POST",
   url:"index.php",
   data: {'hashString':hashString},
   success: function() {
      console.log("message sent!");
   }
});
```

Comment: `data` can be an `Object` or `String`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax ({
   type: "POST",
   url:"index.php",
   data: {"hashString":hashString},
   success: function() {
      console.log("message sent!");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var queryString = "f_name=" + f_name + "&l_name=" + l_name + "&contact_no=" + contact_no + "&email=" + email;
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'insert1.php',
    data:queryString,
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(success){
console.log("message sent!");
}
});
```